# Kohana subdirectory controllers (The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.)

Tags: php, routes, kohana, subdirectory

Trying to call controllers in controllers/api/v1/ folder in browser. It was working on localhost properly but i get a kohana error after moving to server :

```
if ( ! class_exists($prefix.$controller))
        {
            throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404,
                'The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.',
                array(':uri' => $request->uri())                )->request($request);
        }
        // Load the controller using reflection
        $class = new ReflectionClass($prefix.$controller);
```

Init:

```
Kohana::init(array(
'base_url'   => '/',
'index_file' => FALSE,
```

));

Here are my routes:

```
Route::set('api', 'api/v1(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(

    'directory' => 'api/v1',
    'controller' => 'admin',
    'action'     => 'index',
));

Route::set('subsource', 'api/v1/<controller>(/<id>(/<action>))')
->defaults(array(

    'directory' => 'api/v1',
    'controller' => 'admin',
    'action'     => 'index',
));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Controllers name start with Controller_Api_V1_

Controllers in /controllers/ folder are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, you need a new externel request. Here are the documentation: [Requests](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/requests)

Comment: I'm trying to call controllers in browser

Comment: If your server is a linux, the file names are case sensitive?